# 2 seperate installation 1 theme same server

Tags: customization, themes

i got 2 separate installation on the same folder
each in their own sub folder - they use the same theme
which i copied twice.

Every time i edit a file i need to do it twice and its
a real hassle...  How can i define so that they both
use the same theme - a shared theme but a different
database?

I have no "initial code" to share since i don't know
where to begin so an example code would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three fast and easy options™:

1. Setup revision control (git) for your theme and just pull/push the data around.
2. [WordPress Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)
3. Create a symlink to your theme folders

Option 1 is the best because it's doesn't matter which theme you edit.

Comment: Option 2 might not be the best option, because of the way some themes/plugins deals with paths... But on the first one I'm totally with @wyck

Comment: Can you please offer an example for #2 ? I'm also interested.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wyck i would actually love to keep it all "in house" and using git might mess things up while i learn to use it (which i should take the time to - i know ;) - also... i dont want to touch the server so symlink / alias is out.  Can't i keep it all in the theme folder? do you know of any other way to do this?

Comment: Git is the only way I would personally do this, it is the only foolproof method, or using WordPress Network.

Comment: Wordpress network also has the downside that both sites will share the same user table. Git is really the best option and you can't screw anything up if you only use the basic commands.

Comment: Another option is to use the same installation, with detection of the domain in the `.htaccess` to switch prefix database - so any upgrade or change of theme will impact both sites. Potential problem is sharing the same plugin folder if the sites uses different ones.

Comment: Option 3.5: register a new theme directory via `register_theme_directory()`